# Data-sharing attribute of class member variables in OpenMP

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I am having a hard time parallelising a program. I have a class `Program` which contains some variables (e.g. opencv Mat) and a function `run`.

```
class Program {
    Mat image;
    ...
    void run( string inputFileName ) {
       ...
       someFunctionInAnotherFile( image, ... ); // call by reference, image gets manipulated
    }
    ...
};

int main( ) {
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(inputVector)
  Program program;

  #pragma omp for schedule(guided,1)
  for( unsigned int inputNumber = 0; inputNumber < inputVector.size( ); ++inputNumber ) {
    program.run( inputVector[ inputNumber ] );
}
}
```

The variable `program` should be private since declared inside the `parallel` region, right? But what about the member `image`, will it also be private? I could not find anything about it in the openMP specs, only information about dynamicaly stored variables (but what storage class are class members?).
`run` itself calls functions defined in some other .cpp files. Will the local variables inside these functions be private? I hope so.
The big problem: There are race conditions, notable because the outcome changes between multiple program executions. So the question to answer should be something like "How can there be any single shared variable which causes races in this program?"
Any help investigating this problem is highly appreciated, I will also happily supply additional information if needed.
EDIT:
I just discovered that the files containing the other functions contain global variables. Could this be a problem? I guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem indeed were the global variables introduced in other files. The answer to my initial question is:
The class member variables will inherit the data-sharing attribute of the object they belong to. If I got it right, this only holds as long as you do not use `new` for class instantiation, though.